# crashlytics does not get exception crash affected by Umeng SDK

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am debugging a bug that if my app encounter a crash caused by some exceptions, but crashlytics does not get it. I turned on crashlytics debug mode, and finding out after I crash my app and connect it to Xcode, crashlytics is saying no files to send out.

But if I use a [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; I will get the report and crashlytics are printing in Xcode saying sending out file.

I read about on web side saying

"Keep in mind that exceptions are not guaranteed to a crash.  (The full code path, including code in system libraries matters here.)”

However I believe crashlytics should be able to catch my crash, it did crashed, but crashlytics don’t find out file. Is anything I did wrong?

The log:

```
2015-02-13 13:34:11.344 Compass[1589:277586] [Crashlytics] Settings loaded
2015-02-13 13:34:11.351 Compass[1589:277586] [Crashlytics] Configuring application
2015-02-13 13:34:11.352 Compass[1589:277586] [Crashlytics] Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
2015-02-13 13:34:12.451 Compass[1589:277587] [Crashlytics] Alternate file submission complete
2015-02-13 13:34:12.453 Compass[1589:277587] [Crashlytics] No prepared files found
2015-02-13 13:34:12.454 Compass[1589:277587] [Crashlytics] No sendable files, submission process complete
2015-02-13 13:34:13.272 Compass[1589:277585] [Crashlytics] Configured application
```

compared to [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]:

```
2015-02-13 15:36:11.716 Compass[1634:288568] [Crashlytics] Processed file successfully
2015-02-13 15:36:11.717 Compass[1634:288568] [Crashlytics] Alternate file submission complete
2015-02-13 15:36:11.718 Compass[1634:288568] [Crashlytics] Submitting files
2015-02-13 15:36:13.750 Compass[1634:288561] [Crashlytics] Submission response: {status: 202, error: (null)}
2015-02-13 15:36:13.751 Compass[1634:288561] [Crashlytics] Submitted crash report with file name: "54dda95f01cf0001065d333333376237.cls", request-id: <none received>
2015-02-13 15:36:13.752 Compass[1634:288569] [Crashlytics] Submitted file successfully
2015-02-13 15:36:13.754 Compass[1634:288569] [Crashlytics] No sendable files, submission process complete
```

and crashlytics don't report I am missing dSYMs:

Yay! We are not missing any impactful dSYMs

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics never sends report for handled exception.
if you are using try-catch block then add below lines in your catch block

```
@try {
// your code here
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *handler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();
handler(exception);
}
```